# Undefined variable 'token'

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php

session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db");

if (!isset($_SESSION['lodge'])) {
    header("Location: lodge.php");
}
$token = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['token']);
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM lodges WHERE lodge_id=" . $_SESSION['lodge']); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
if ($row['token'] == ($token)) {
    $_SESSION['lodge'] = $row['lodge_id'];
    header('location:lodge.php');
}

?>
```

I keep getting the `undefined variable token` error, and can't seem find my way around this.

Comment: var_dump($_POST), check it

Comment: *"I keep getting the undefined variable error"* - for which one?

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: for the variable "token"

Comment: Oh my "duh", it was in the question's title *lol*

Comment: yup.its in the question

Comment: ok now my question should have been: for which line? You have a few.

Comment: line 9 $token =mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['token']);

Comment: It means you don't have any `token` variable passed in the POST ones. You should test its existence with `isset($_POST['token'])` before using it.

Comment: please elaborate using the code.I dont understand

Comment: I solved it:i simply set token to empty like this:$token = "";...i declared token before the select all in table query.And it works perfectly.So basically $token = ""; is declared as an empty string to append later.